# Tensorflow Object Detection API Index out of Bounds

Tags: android, tensorflow, object-detection

Upon running the Android TF Detect Demo and using my retrained 3 class ssd_mobilenet_v1_coco model my TF detect Demo crashes giving an **IndexOutOfBoundException** which is

> 12-26 17:53:13.931 22429-25212/org.tensorflow.demo E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: inference
>                                                                        Process: org.tensorflow.demo, PID: 22429
>                                                                        java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: length=3; index=3
>                                                                            at java.util.Vector.arrayIndexOutOfBoundsException(Vector.java:907)
>                                                                            at java.util.Vector.elementAt(Vector.java:328)
>                                                                            at java.util.Vector.get(Vector.java:442)
>                                                                            at org.tensorflow.demo.TensorFlowObjectDetectionAPIModel.recognizeImage(TensorFlowObjectDetectionAPIModel.java:194)
>                                                                            at org.tensorflow.demo.DetectorActivity$3.run(DetectorActivity.java:289)
>                                                                            at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>                                                                            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                                                                            at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)

which comes from

```
for (int i = 0; i <= outputScores.length; ++i) {
  final RectF detection =
      new RectF(
          outputLocations[4 * i + 1] * inputSize,
          outputLocations[4 * i] * inputSize,
          outputLocations[4 * i + 3] * inputSize,
          outputLocations[4 * i + 2] * inputSize);

  pq.add(new Recognition("" + i, labels.get((int) outputClasses[i]), outputScores[i], detection));
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Solved by Adding a "???" string inside my Label file, it seems that the App follows the pbtxt format of having the first ID which is 1.